# How can I jump to a cell reference

Tags: google-sheets

Imagine I have a cell with a formula such as:

```
=RHSP!$Z$669
```

Where this cell gets the contents of Z, row 669 of sheet RHSP.

Is there a shortcut to hover over that cell and jump to Z669?  What's the fastest way to either highlight or go to the target range of a formula in Google Sheets?

Comment: Choose one, Google Sheets or Excel Online. You might post a another question for the other web application. P.S. Title should not include tags. Ref. https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/tagging

Answer (score 3):

For this your example, everything is simple: **F2** to enter cell editing, **Shift+Home** to select the entire formula, **Ctrl+C** to copy it to the clipboard. Now **Ctrl+J** to go into editing the ***Name Box***, **Ctrl+V** and **Enter**.

For more complex cases, when the code in the formula has references to several cells or ranges, instead of Shift+Home, you will have to use more keys - arrows and, possibly, Ctrl.